# React Native animations - translateX and translateY while scaling

Tags: animation, react-native

My `Animated.View` has the following style:

```
    {
        transform: [
            {
                scale: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                    outputRange: [initialScale, 1]
            })},
            {
                translateX: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                    outputRange: [startX, endX]
            })},
            {
                translateY: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                    outputRange: [startY, endY]
            })},
        ]
    }
```

When initialScale is 1 and the animation starts, I see the expected behavior: Animated.View starts at (startX, startY) and linearly moves to (endX, endY). 
 However, when initialScale is 0.5 for example, the starting point of the view is not (startX, startY), the movement is not linear (a bit spheric) and the end point is still as expected - (endX, endY).

How can I scale my View while keeping a linear movement and expected start position?

Comment: When you scale the view it keeps the original centerX (thus moving to the right). When you translate the same view it will then translate from the seemingly offset position. If you use two wrapped views, scaling the inner one and translating the outer one, you may get the outcome you are expecting.

Comment: This helps with the spheric movement but the start position is still off

Comment: If you could set transform-origin you could probably make it scale toward the upper right corner. However, transform-origin is not supported in react-native. You *can* however [use transformMatrix](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1964#issuecomment-222480415) to define your transformation instead, although that's a whole other way of doing it.

Comment: That would present an issue for android because android does not suppose overflow: 'visible'  @AmeoHugo

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Like the user @ArneHugo pointed out in the comments, the non-linear movement can be solved by positioning the full-size container element and scaling another element within it.

The position of the element is not as expected, because the origin for the scale transform is the center point of the element. React Native doesn't (yet) support specifying the transform origin, but if the width and height of the scaled element are known in advance, it's easy to calculate the offset as follows:

```jsx
const width = 100;
const height = 20;
const scale = {
  transform: [
    {
      scale: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [initialScale, 1]
      })
    }
  ]
};

const position= {
  transform: [
    {
      translateX: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [startX - (width / 2) - (width * initialScale / 2), endX]
      })
    },
    {
      translateY: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [startY - (height / 2) - (height * initialScale / 2), endY]
      })
    }
  ]
};

return (
  <Animated.View style={position}>
    <Animated.View style={[styles.thing, scale]} />
  </Animated.View>
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Made a little change to the formula and it did the magic (also edited the change in your post)

Comment: thanks, this is super helpful! Where is `animatedValue` coming from?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this problem by using scale factor for positioning:

```
imageScale = new Animated.Value(1);
imageX = new Animated.Value(0);
imageY = new Animated.Value(0);
...
<Animated.Image source={item} style={[styles.image, {
    transform:[
        {scale: this.imageScale},
        {translateX: Animated.divide(this.imageX,this.imageScale)},
        {translateY: Animated.divide(this.imageY,this.imageScale)},
    ]
}]}/>
```

If you use interpolation, this looks a bit complicated but the idea remains the same:

```
transform: [
  {
    scale: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [initialScale, 1]
  })},
  {
    translateX: Animated.divide(
      this.animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [startX, endX]
      }),
      this.animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [initialScale, 1]
      })
    )
}]
```